# How can click.exacttarget.com recognize encoded email address string or relating plan string with encoded string is needed?

Tags: marketing-cloud, conversion

I have a question for encoding email address string in conversion link.

When I encode email address string using AMPScript, after clicking conversion link, can the "click.exacttarget.com" automatically read or recognize hashed string as the email address?

If it is yes, how click.exacttarget.com recognize hashed string equal registered email address?

Can anyone tell me how I can relate "email address" and "hashed string" if there is some functions (i.e. ContactBuilder) to do so?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [EncryptSymmetric](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/encryption/EncryptSymmetric.html) method for encoding and the [DecryptSymmeritc](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/encryption/DecryptSymmetric.html) method for decoding the email. These methods support the AES, DES and TripleDES algorithms.